# Annoying whatsdesk on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, whatsapp

I am using whatsdesk on my Ubuntu desktop computer as whatsapp client. Since I upgraded from Ubuntu 20.04 to 22.04 is it showing undesired behavior: every time a message comes in the application gets activated, the window pops up to be the top window and becomes the active window. If I happen to be typing something else (e.g. a document) the text gets inserted in whatsdesk and not the document I was working on. I am not sure but believe that I used to have a GNOME extension on 20.04 which would prevent pop ups. That extension is no longer working on 22.04.
How can I prevent whatsdesk to pop up and steal the focus every time a message comes in?

Answer (score 0):

In 22.04 many of the original GNOME extensions from earlier GNOME versions are now unsupported.

However, by installing `Extension Manager` in 22.04 new extensions to replace the unsupported ones are available.If `Extension Manager` not already installed, it is available from Ubuntu Software.

The extension for GNOME 42 is `NoAnnoyance v2` which removes the "window is ready" notification and is actively maintained.
[image]

Comment: Thank you for this recommendation. I do have the `Extension Manager` installed. I will try this extension and see whether it does what I am looking for.

Comment: Unfortunately that recommended extension does not prevent whatsdesk from popping up when a new message arrives. I have also tried an extension called `NoAnnoyance v2` but that one doesn't work either.

Comment: what is the name of the extension you used to use in 20.04? As an alternative to `Whatsdesk` I use web.whatsapp.com which doesn't perform the actins you complain of.

Comment: I used an GNOME extension called `NoAnnoyance` in Ubuntu 20.04. It stopped working in Ubuntu 22.04. I will try the whatsapp web interface.

Comment: aha.. that's now called `NoAnnoyance v2` you may be able to install it using GNOME `Extension Manager`. It seems to be supported.

Comment: I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: See my previous comment: `NoAnnoyance v2` is already installed but does not work.

Comment: any joy with web.whatsapp then?

Comment: I have tried web.whatsapp for a while. It has benefits and disadvantages. Benefit: when a message comes in the (Firefox) instance will not expand and steal the focus. Disadvantage: there is no indication at all whether a new message has arrived. The benefit of whatsdesk is that when it is running minimized it shows the number of unread messages in its icon. I will continue my search for the most optimum solution for me.

Comment: In FF running web.whatsapp there is a red marker under the icon to show there is a message...